# Find the sum of the residuals

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, poisson

I am doing a hands on exercise of Poissons Regression of Stats with Python in Fresco Play. 
    Problem statement is like:
    Load the R dataset Insurance from the MASS package.
    Capture the data as a pandas dataframe.
    Build a Poisson regression model with a log of an independent variable 
    Holders, and dependent variable Claims.
    Fit the model with data, and find the sum of the residuals.

I am stuck with the last line i.e. Sum of Residuals

I used `np.sum(model.resid)`. But answer is not accepted

Here is my code

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np

INS_data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Insurance','MASS').data
model = smf.poisson('Claims ~ np.log(Holders)', INS_data).fit()
print(np.sum(model.resid))
```

Comment: Did you get an error when you used np.sum? Or did it not give the right answer?

Comment: @cenh I got answer. No error. But answer is not accepted.

Comment: Do you need a sum or a cumulative sum by any chance?

Comment: @Dalen As per questions, it should be sum.

Comment: What form does model.resid take? What kind of data container and its values types and ranges? Did you take a look? Try np.cumsum() instead of np.sum(), just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the code in Python2 which gave wrong answer but running it in Python3 gave the correct answer. I don't know the reason but code works perfectly in Python3

Comment: @ 

It's not working for me. I have tried in Python 3 env. I am getting below Output, Is it correct?

Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 3.468160
         Iterations 7
6.679101716144942e-13

Answer (score 0):

For residual, you can use the basic concept of residual i.e. **actual - predicted**.

Here is the code snippet.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
Insurance = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('Insurance','MASS')
data = Insurance.data
data['Holders_'] = np.log(data['Holders'])
model = smf.poisson('Claims ~ Holders_',data).fit()
y_predicted = p.predict(data['Holders_'])
residual = (data['Claims']-y_predicted)
print(sum(residual))
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uQW8.png)

Answer (score -1):

After much serach, i came to know that it is expecting cumulative sum so use
np.cumsum(model.resid)
It will pass in Frescoplay

Comment: Please update the grammar of your answer, it is very hard to understand